# $ \frac{\pi}{6} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-jx\sin(\tau)}d\tau + \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi m^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{2m\tau-x\sin(\tau)}d\tau $

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

## Introduction

I'm grappling with an expression that intriguingly combines integrals and series, involving exponential functions with sinusoidal inputs. I'm curious about expressing this in terms of a Fourier series.

### Expression

The expression in question is:

$$
\frac{\pi}{6} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-jx\sin(\tau)}d\tau + \sum_{m \neq 0, m=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi m^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{2m\tau-x\sin(\tau)}d\tau
$$

### Context and Motivation

My interest stems from potential applications in signal processing and the mathematical beauty of Fourier and Bessel functions, often intertwined in physical and engineering problems.

### Approach and Challenges

I've attempted direct integration and series summation, confronting significant computational challenges, particularly with the series involving infinite terms and the complex nature of the integrals.

### Objective

- **Question:** Can we represent the above expression in Fourier series terms?
- **Goal:** Identify methods or transformations that could simplify the expression, possibly leveraging properties of special functions.

### Why It Matters

This inquiry spans several mathematical and physical disciplines, potentially enriching our toolkit for tackling wave analysis, differential equations, and beyond.

**Insights, strategies, or any form of guidance are deeply appreciated.**

Comment: When $m=0$, the sum is undefined?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash thank you, yes, it was a typo, edited.